# Problem with SPAdes installation - no bin folder

Tags: assembly

I have been trying to download SPAdes for an important project I wanted to do, however, I have encountered a small problem while doing so. It appears that there is no 'bin' folder in my SPAdes installation file.

I have used 7-Zip as my main method of unpacking the file (As I am using Windows, I had to download the actual source code rather than a nice executable), and it came in the `.tar.gz` format, which I believe 7-Zip is rather good with.

A few pictures detailing my problems are shown below.

I hope I can get a little help on this matter. It is slightly time-sensitive, so I would really appreciate a little bit of assistance shortly. Thank you in advance!

[image: This is the command I used, the usual test command][image: This is the file structure I got. Notice the absence of the 'bin' file.]

[image: This is the error I received from running the <code>spades.py --test</code> command]

As seen above, the first image is the command I used, the usual test command, the second is the file structure I got (Notice the absence of the 'bin' file), and the third is the error I received from running the `spades.py --test` command.

Comment: I see that it supports Linux and MacOS. It appears you are using Windows. Is there a reason you believe that Windows is supported? See https://github.com/ablab/spades/issues/156

Comment: No, not at all. I just thought the source code would work on Windows, as there are options for Linux and MacOS downloadables.

Comment: Well, sure, 7-Zip will unzip a tar.gz file, but it won't install software for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply unpacking the source code won't actually install much, you'll need to follow its installation instructions. Note that this might be possible on Windows if you use new bash command line, but in general don't expect any bioinformatics tools to work on windows.